# How to order text using css?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple text which in desktop looks like this:

```
Kolor : Niebieski
Rozmiar : S/M
```

I want this to look like this in mobile:

```
Kolor : Niebieski Rozmiar : S/M
```

Here is the html:

```
<a href="">Kolor : Niebieski<br> Rozmiar : S/M</a>
```

Here is css I have tried:

```
div br {
  display: none;
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work, any suggestion what I need to do to get what I want without changing html structure?

Comment: Why `div br` instead of `a br`?

Comment: If you wrap your code in a div it works fine.

Comment: probably a *stupid* question, but why in mobile you want the text to take more width? shouldn't be the opposite, wrap text on mobile?

Comment: Unfoetunatelly that is what I needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide the br on smaller screens:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { /* change this to be the width when you want it to go one one line */
  br {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="">Kolor : Niebieski<br> Rozmiar : S/M</a>
```

I would say that you should keep them on separate lines though as it now doesn't read correctly and looks worse on mobiles

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
div br{
display: inline-block;
}
```

It should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML you show

```
<a href="">Kolor : Niebieski<br> Rozmiar : S/M</a>
```

while in your CSS you use

```
div br { display: none; }
```

To hide the `<br />` on mobile, you need to target it correctly:

```
a br { display: none; }
```

To only do it on mobile, you need to put that inside a media query:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  a br { display: none; }
}
```

Of course you need to replace the `480px` by whatever is the breakpoint between mobile and desktop display.